# Crystal Reports - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: window

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I recently came across an unusual error when attempting to load a crystal report form into my WPF application via a dialog, the report would show as loading for a few seconds and then throw an error stating "**Value cannot be null. Parameter name: window**"

This confused me, as far as i know, crystal reports doesn't use a parameter named window.

This was my code:

A simple window with a `CrystalReportsViewer`

```
<Window x:Class="Client.Views.ReportsWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
    Title="ReportsWindowView" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <my:CrystalReportsViewer ShowOpenFileButton="True" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ReportView"/>
</Grid>
```

and loading the report from code behind (I've removed the standard ConnectionInfo code for simplicity)

```
 cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
 cryRpt.Load("report.rpt");
 ReportView.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that Crystal Reports Does indeed use a parameter named window, when it attempts to show an internal error.

`CrystalReportsViewer`  handles internal an error and will try to show a MessageBox:

`System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Window owner, String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)`

Show method get u201CWindow owneru201D parameter and  CrystalReportsViewer tries pass Owner property CrystalReportsViewer.Owner, however by default owner is null, as such we get this unexpected error.

A simple fix for this, is in the codebehind (even when using mvvm) we simply set the owner to the current window via the following code:

```
ReportView.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Do this in the OnLoaded Event or similar, and you will find that now you get a messagebox with an internal error thrown by `CrystalReportsViewer`.

Credit for this solution belongs to this [thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2155371)