# System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, business-objects

[image: Details of error]

This error is showed when I try to print a crystal report.

> System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

I am trying to build a `WPF` application,
I have used the same code in another form, and it's working fine there.
but at this page it shows error.

```
private void btnReciept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if (txtComplainNo.Text == "")
        {
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Enter Complain Number","ErrorFound", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            InsertFinalReport();
            var ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GalaxyApp.Properties.Settings.ConnString"].ConnectionString;
            string CmdString = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter MyDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet myDS = new DataSet(); 
            // DataSet1 myDS = new DataSet1();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from FinalReport where ComplainNo='" + Convert.ToInt32(txtComplainNo.Text) + "'";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            MyDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
            MyDA.Fill(myDS, "FinalReport");
            // FinalReportDS myDS = new FinalReportDS();
            // myDS.EnforceConstraints=false;
            if (myDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                ModernDialog.ShowMessage("EmptyDataSet", "ErrorFound", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                CourierReport1 rpt = new CourierReport1();
                rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
                FinalReportViewer FRV = new FinalReportViewer();
                FRV.ReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpt;
                FRV.Show();
            }
            //Report frm1 = new Report();
            //frm1.ReportViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpt;
            //frm1.Show();
            ///*
            //Form1 mform = new Form1();
            //mform.ShowReport(Convert.ToInt32(txtComplainNo.Text));
            //mform.Show();
            //*/
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "ErrorFound", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

I tried every alternative code.
Please anyone can help me in finding cause of this error

[image: Error Image]

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper..ctor(Window window)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Window owner, String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)
   at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore.HandleExceptionEvent(Object eventSource, Exception e, Boolean suppressMessage)
   at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ReportAlbum.OnHandleException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at GalaxyApp.App.Main() in D:\GoogleDrive\extra\GalaxyApp\GalaxyApp\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
Stack Trace:
```

Comment: Please post all the exception details. You're passing null to some function or constructor.

Comment: I have posted picture also you can check that

Comment: @SudhirSolka Is this crystal reports ? It looks like it, if so please add the tag to your question.

Comment: @Blacktempel i tagged it as it crystal reports also

Comment: @SudhirSolka A comment on a question does not indicate that the person is able to help with your specific issue. _In this case it helps people who are trying to help you._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little 'bug' in CrystalReports to not show any helpful exception details on some occasions. I've also encountered it recently.

The issue is exceptional hard to find as the exception says basically nothing at all... and the problem might aswell be in the report, not the code itself.
You will sadly have to debug through AND check your reports if there's anything wrong with it.

***Check all details.***
Check the used DB-tables and columns...

I had the problem, that a sub-report had a couple of parameters, which the parent also had. But these were not passed automatically to the sub-report. It is necessary to give the report all required parameters. Maybe this helps you too. Sadly hard to tell without the report, code and environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Every one Specially @Blacktempe who asked me to tag this question as crystal report i found the answer from this thread [Crystal Reports - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655875/crystal-reports-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-window)?